# Are these artifacts or just graphical glitches?

Tags: modeling

When I switch from object mode to edit mode and from a certain angle the vertical edges turn into those doted lines. Is there only a display issue or a real topology issue? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: OMG, sorry, but how hard is switch to wire mode and check topology (unwanted vertices), or try render it (shift+Z) for check if this will be visible on render ? You can solve this by yourself in less than 1 minute ;-)  Anyway, the answer is: these are graphics glitches, nothing to do with topology. Probably your mesh is small and you zooming to close.

Comment: I'm totally new and there is certainly a lack of precision in my question. I should have titled "how can I check if the topology is good or not". Thanks for your answer that helps. PS:1 munute for an expert like you could mean 1 hour for a newbie like me ;-)

Comment: I just ... can't see any glitches... maybe buy a new screen ?

Comment: On the three last vertical edges you can see doted line. I added so much mean crease at 1 that I am wondering if it's a good workflow to keep edges sharp?

Comment: To me it looks like the viewport Ambient Occlusion, please, try turning it off. Steps: Press *N* to open the right Toolbar, scroll to find the *Shading* tab and uncheck the **Ambient Occlusion** checkbox.